# Wow! Nice! I smelled you baking cake!

Tags: pronouns, possessives, present-participles

Which one is grammatical?

> "Wow! Nice! I smelled **you baking cake**!"
>   "Wow! Nice! I smelled **your baking cake**!"

Both of them are acceptable, maybe?

Comment: The second one sounds tricky. But I think it's okay because I feel it's similar to patterns of my+ gerund I've come across recently. I think it's a bit formal?

Comment: You know that I am not given to giving answers!

Comment: Both are correct, though the second is awkward because while both are referring to 'baking' as an object, or at least part of an object phrase, the second refers to an action being owned, which while unusual, is still correct. The first is generally preferred.

Comment: Your first version sounds fine, but your 2nd version sounds off to my AmE ear. Perhaps this is related to a tidbit in *CGEL*, page 1238, [49] (about the catenative "smell" not allowing a genitive as subject in the -ing clause), maybe. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are idiomatic:

> I smelled you smoking out in the tool shed, you little twerp. I'm going to tell Dad on you. An eight-year-old shouldn't be smoking.
>
> Did I smell you burning dead leaves last night? The breeze brought the scent in our window.
>
> I smelled you frying fish.

I would not use "your" with any of those actions. But I'm not sure why. Because the transitive verb *smell* demands a *smellable* object? A noun phrase like "your frying fish" is, as a kind of possessive abstraction, inherently unsmellable, whereas "you frying" is closer to "raw" reality?  Just a half-baked conjecture.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how these structures are different? *I smelled you baking cake!" AND "I saw you running hard!"

Comment: I don't see any difference in the structure. Both are verbs of perception, both use "you" not "your".

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are grammatically sound.

> "Wow! Nice! I smelled **you baking cake**!"

Here you're referring to the whole action. For this reason, this is what would normally be said. The action of cake baking generates an aroma that fills the whole kitchen and that's what is being smelled.

If it wasn't cake baking but something else, it's possible that it would be interpreted as "I smelled *you*, whilst you were [doing action]". However, it's clear from context here that it's the cake baking that's being smelled.

> "Wow! Nice! I smelled **your baking cake**!"

Here you're referring to the cake specifically. You might say it, for example, if the chef was out of the kitchen, you came in and smelled the cake, and then the chef came back in and you told them about it.

However, in general, the first form is more usual.

Comment: In the second example, where you have taken "the cake specifically" as the object: in the US we would say "I smelled your cake baking" rather than "baking cake".